# Is there a way to check if a particular flutter plugin will work with a particular Android/IOS operating version?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'd like to know if there is a way to determine if a flutter plugin will operate on a particular Android or IOS operating version?

For example would a flutter plugin like:
https://pub.dev/packages/http/

Work on android version 6 and older?
I expect that it would be dependent on the version of the plugin I'm intending to use.
Is there an easy way to check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view `build.gralde` file for check minimum Android version and `plugin_name.podspec` file (where `plugin_name` is name of the plugin) for minimum iOS requirements. Many plugins on `pub.dev` contains links to its source code (on GitHub or etc.)).

`build.gradle` contains in `android` folder, and you need to find line like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
}
```

`plugin_name.podspec` file contains in `ios` folder, you need to find like this:

```rb
s.platform = :ios, '9.0'
```

Config files also contains more information about what version of Language plugin using.